# ArangoDB create Vertex REST API without knowing the vertex id's

Tags: rest, arangodb

Is there a way to create with ArangoDB an Edge with REST API without knowing the Vertex ids? With a query to find the vertexs and link them?

Like this with OrientDB: create edge Uses from (select from Module where name = 'm2') to (select from Project where name = 'p1')

I don't want to query via REST the two vertex before, and after create the Edge. I don't want to use Foxx also.

Perhaps with AQL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is doable with a single AQL query:

```
LET from = (FOR doc IN Module FILTER doc.name == 'm2' RETURN doc._id)
LET to   = (FOR doc IN Project FILTER doc.name == 'p1' RETURN doc._id)
INSERT { 
  _from: from[0], 
  _to: to[0], 
  /* insert other edge attributes here as needed */ 
  someOtherAttribute: "someValue" 
}
INTO nameOfEdgeCollection
```

Comment: Great! But it is not working in the REST API.

The same AQL bellow works fine in the AQL editor.


curl -X POST --dump - http://localhost:8529/_db/database/_api/cursor --data '{query:LET from = (FOR p IN products FILTER p.name == "p1" RETURN p._id) LET to=(FOR p IN products FILTER p.name == "p2" RETURN p._id) INSERT { _from: from[0], _to: to[0], type: "RELATED" } INTO productsedge}' 

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Server: ArangoDB Connection: Keep-Alive Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 Content-Length: 82 {"error":true,"errorMessage":"expecting attribute name","code":400,"errorNum":600}

Comment: You will need to make sure to send correctly encoded JSON to the server. The above data is no valid JSON, because neither attribute names nor values are enclosed in double quotes. It should rather be `curl ... --data '{"query":"LET from = (FOR p IN products FILTER p.name == \"p1\" RETURN p._id) LET to=(FOR p IN products FILTER p.name == \"p2\" RETURN p._id) INSERT { _from: from[0], _to: to[0], type: \"RELATED\" } INTO productsedge"}'`